# React page not working when dynamically loaded with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax, iframe

I try to load 3rd party's webpage into our web page.
When I load a 3rd party's webpage made with react, the page doesn't loaded.
It's the same when I load the page in an iframe.
I can't give you the sample because of the security problem, but is anyone knows the problem like this?

The page should loaded and render the component in the root-div, but it seems not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.